# How to update react context between components?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-context

I have two sibling components (A & B) that I'm trying to pass react context between. Not static context. The context is created and updated in component A like so:

```
  export const ModelContext = React.createContext({ model: '' });

function Models() {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState({});
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
    let model = useContext(ModelContext);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const arr = Object.keys(check);
        if (arr.length === 1 && arr.includes(event.target.name) === false) {
            setAlert(true);
        } else if (arr.length === 1 && arr.includes(event.target.name) === true) {
            setAlert(false);
            setCheck({});
            model = check;
            console.log(model);
        } else {
            setCheck({ ...check, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
            setAlert(false);
        }
    };
```

I update the context (ModelContext) in this component in the handleChange. I can see from the console.log(model) that the context is updating as I desire.

However, in component B the context (ModelContext) is not being updated. I'm not sure where to go from here. Here is component B:

```
import { ModelContext } from './index';


function Fields() {
    const modelSelected = useContext(ModelContext);
```

}

Is it possible to update the context in this fashion or should I take another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in the console log is after updating the model object. It is no longer referring to the context. It has a new reference now after `model=check`.

First of all, if you want to pass the context between 2 siblings, the common parent should be wrapped around with context providers. You can create a context provider component.

```
const ModelContext = useContext({model: ''});
const ContextProvider = ({children, modelData}) => {
   const [model, setModel] = useState(modelData);
   return <ModelContext.Provider value={{model, setModel}}>{children}</ModelContext.Provider>
}


const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <ContextProvider modelData={your model data}>
           <Models />
           <Fields/>
        </ContextProvider>        
    )
}

const Models = () => {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState({});
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);
    const {model, setModel} = useContext(ModelContext);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const arr = Object.keys(check);
        if (arr.length === 1 && arr.includes(event.target.name) === false) {
            setAlert(true);
        } 
        else if (arr.length === 1 && arr.includes(event.target.name)===true) {
           setAlert(false);
           setCheck({});
           setModel(check);
           console.log(model);
        } else {
           setCheck({ ...check, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
           setAlert(false);
        }
   };

   const Fields = () => {
      const {model: modelSelected} = useContext(ModelContext);
      console.log(modelSelected);
   }
```

You have to do this because, the context doesn't automatically get to the siblings if you do not wrap their parent with the context provider. [This](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/)
blog might be helpful for you to understand the usage of context